# Django if statement with beginning tag in conditional breaking next div

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates

I have the following code in a file in my template folder

```
{% if permission <= 4 %}
  <div class='row'>
```

The `<` in my conditional is breaking my next div.

If I use `>` then it works but that's not how I have my permissions and I don't want to switch it around.

vim detects a break in this conditional by changing the color and the template never loads the div even though the conditional is true.

Session output:
`('permission', 0)])`

I feel like I'm missing something simple but I can't quite get my search strings to give me what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me here: https://forum.djangoproject.com/t/conditional-conflict-in-template-with-following-div/14476

I got distracted by the VIM error and went in the wrong direction.
I changed 'permission' to 'request.session.permission' and it works now.